# Add a new column and row to existing CSV data in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to add the new column and row/content to the existing CSV data but unable to achieve this in Apache Camel
I have used camel-csv component in the code and below is the snippet for the same.

```
<unmarshal>
    <csv delimiter="|" useMaps="true" lazyLoad="true" />
</unmarshal>
```

When unmarshalling, getting "org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvUnmarshaller$CsvIterator" as class name but unable to get the exchange or cast to any type to this class as this is abstract class.

Let me know if we can use bean component and solution to add the column and content to the existing CSV data.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an alternative solution. You can use BeanIO Data Format.

E.g :

```
BeanIODataFormat dataFormat = new BeanIODataFormat("classpath:beanio/mappings.xml", "ContactsCSV");

from("direct:convert-to-csv")    
.marshal(dataFormat)
.to("file:xxxx")
.end();
```

You can find check data format details in [docs.](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/beanio-dataformat.html) There is an examples file in there as well.